# Create points along line at alternating sides using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line

I want to create points along a polyline.

The distance between each „nearest-to-point“ position on the line and the shortest distance of each point to the line should be 2 parameters that can be set before creating this point layer. The points should also alternate the sides.

The wished result would loke like the this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). For someone to provide you with an answer, it is expected that you share what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: since i am a greenhorn, i stuck at the very beginning. so it was not possible to fulfil these requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisgeometrybyexpression) with the expression:

```
nodes_to_points( triangular_wave( $geometry, 100, 10))
```

It will create a zigzag-wave along the line where 100 is the wavelength and 10 the amplitude, then extract the vertices:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was searching for. The expression does not work. Are there pre-settings that I have to keep attention to?

Comment: Do you have some old version of QGIS?

Comment: yes, that was the problem, thanks!

Comment: Nice! Please accept my answer with the checkbox